# Why x86 places arguments on stack?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, mips

In MIPS arguments are placed in $a0 to $a4 registers for faster accesses. Why some x86 architectures make the design choice to place arguments on stack instead of in registers? What are the advantages of doing this?

Comment: The premise of your question is fatally flawed.  There is no processor-based requirement that arguments must be on the stack, nor any restriction on using registers for passing arguments.  Take a look at the original IBM PC BIOS: the BIOS has routines with arguments passed in the registers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Registers are naturally faster, considerably faster, but you have to have enough of them.  x86 traditionally had very few registers so a stack based approach was the way to go, at that time in history it was in general the way to go, risc and others came along with a lot more registers and the idea of using registers for the first few parameters and perhaps the return value was now something to consider.  x86 has more registers now but has generally been stack based although I think zortech or watcom or perhaps even gcc now had a command line option to use a few registers, would have to confirm or deny that with research.  but historically it has used the stack for parameters and registers.

ARM, MIPS, etc all have a finite number of registers so eventually dump into the stack, if you keep/control your parameters number and size and at times ordering you can try to limit this and improve performance.

At the end of the day the bottom line is someone or some team defines the calling convention, it is the choice ultimately of the compiler authors, doesnt matter if the chip/processor designer has a recommendation the compiler defines what its calling convention is be it follow a recommendation or do their own thing.  there is no reason to create a MIPS or ARM compiler/toolchain that is mostly stack based (the instruction set itself might dictate stack or register based returns, or it could be optional), likewise you are more than welcome to make an x86 compiler with a convention that starts with registers then moves to the stack after some number of them are used.

so a little bit history and a little bit because they choose to...

Answer (score 5):

The real answer is that it depends more on the compiler than the processor, although I suspect the reason that it is so common for x86 compilers to push arguments onto the stack is that the x86 CPU has always suffered from a scarcity of registers. By the time you eliminate the reserved registers, you are left with three - EAX, ECX, and EDX, which corresponded to AX, CX, and DX in the original 16-bit x86 instruction set. So far as I know, the first processor in the Intel line to raise that limit is the 64 bit "AMD" architecture, which adds eight more, numbered R9 through R15. The five reserved registers get new names, but they remain reserved.

To reinforce my assertion that it depends on the compiler, you need look no further than the native code generator that ships with the Microsoft .NET Framework, which exhibits a hybrid approach, where the first two arguments go into ECX (or RCX) and EDX (or RDX), while additional arguments go onto the stack.

Even within C/C++ code generated by the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler, although the most common calling conventions, __cdecl and __stdcall, use the stack, a third, __fastcall, uses registers. Moreover, I have seen Assembly code that used both; if it needed to talk to C, the routine expected arguments in registers, but private routines that received calls only from other routines in the library used registers.

Comment: Microsoft [fastcall convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xa169sk.aspx) uses ECX and EDX for the first two parameters. The [64 bit calling convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx) uses ECX, EDX, R8, and R9 for the first four parameters (and/or the first four xmm registers for floating point).

Comment: Since I seldom use it, I had forgotten that detail about the fastcall convention. Essentially, then, NGEN is using fastcall.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that you must always follow the ABI for the platform that you are running on.  The longer answer is that you incorrectly assume that every 32 bit x86 platform will exclusively use the stack for argument passing.  In fact, while each platform will adopt a standard, there are numerous approaches, any of which can be used. (fastcall, cdecl, etc.)